# Intuition behind self-inductance

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, gauss-law, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I'm having a little bit of a hard time understanding some concepts to do with self-inductance in class.

I understand mutual inductance. That's when a loop has some time-dependent current going through it, and because the current is time-dependent, the magnetic field the loop produces is also time-dependent, and the magnetic flux in a nearby loop is time-dependent.

With **self**-inductance, though, is the idea that a single loop carrying a time-dependent current gives rise to a time-dependent magnetic field, and that very same time-dependent magnetic field gives rise to a change in flux in the single loop itself, which then generates an emf?

If I'm correct in this reasoning, then that should mean that the new emf gives way to a current, which opposes the previously existing current. Why doesn't this just result in an infinite loop creating an opposing current, and then one that opposes that, and then one that opposes THAT...etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get a general idea for this by considering the case of a battery connected to a series combination of a resistor and a solenoid, the latter of which acts as an inductor.

[image]

Let our solenoid have radius $r$, length $\ell$, and consist of $N$ turns of wire. If a current $I$ is flowing through it, then there will be a magnetic field in the interior of the solenoid given by
$$B = \frac{\mu_0 N I}{\ell}$$

The total magnetic flux through the solenoid is $\Phi_B = 2\pi r^2 NB$. If we apply Faraday's law to the circuit, we obtain the following equation:

$$V_0-IR=-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_B = -2\pi r^2 N \frac{dB}{dt} = -\left[\frac{2\pi \mu_0 r^2 N^2}{\ell}\right]\frac{dI}{dt} \equiv -L\frac{dI}{dt}$$
where $V_0$ is the voltage across the battery and $L$ is called the (self) inductance of the solenoid. Unlike the mutual inductance between two coils - where the current through one coil induces an EMF around the other - here we see that the current through the solenoid induces an EMF across the same solenoid. This is why the effect is called *self*-inductance.

The differential equation takes the form
$$L\frac{dI}{dt} + IR=-V_0$$

Assuming that the circuit is closed at $t=0$ (so no current is flowing yet, $I(0)=0$), the solution to this equation is
$$I(t) = \frac{V_0}{R}\left(1-e^{-tR/L}\right)$$
which you can straightforwardly check.

Answer (score 0):

To fully close your feedback loop, you need to add an admittance. This allows you to calculate a corresponding current from the induced emf (the step of your last paragraph). Physically, you need to close your circuit. This is often modeled by an ohmic resistance, giving an LR circuit as J. Murray described in his answer.

Intuitively, you are describing the alternating power series of the decaying exponential. Even if at each step the new current opposes the previous one, the next contribution is smaller so does not cancel the previous one. Furthermore the terms tend to zero giving you a finite result. Note that it crucially depends on the admittance which relates the emf to the current. For an ohmic resistance, the previous reasoning holds, but it won’t be true in general.

Mathematically, it’s better to think about it the other way round and reverse the order of the feedback. If you have a current, the impedance gives you the voltage. It needs to be canceled by the emf, which then means that it was induced from an additional varying current. By Lenz’ law, this current opposes the original current and you can start over the reasoning with this new current.

For the LR circuit, you have:
$$
L\frac{di}{dt}+Ri=0
$$
Your approach amounts to rewriting it as:
$$
i=\frac{L}{R}\frac{di}{dt}
$$
and solving iteratively:
$$
i_{n+1}=-\frac{L}{R}\frac{di_n}{dt}
$$
The convergence is not very tame. Any polynomial initial guess converges to zero and sinusoidal solutions alternate, which is perhaps why you were perplexed.

The alternative approach rewrites it as:
$$
i=i(0)-\int_0^t i\frac{Rdt’}{L}
$$
and solving iteratively:
$$
i_{n+1}(t)=i(0)-\int_0^t i_n(t’)\frac{Rdt’}{L}
$$
This self consistent method converges better and you get the Taylor series of the exponential.

Hope this helps.